# Attack of electrophile on toluene

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

Does hyperconjugation in toluene influence the attack of an electrophile in any way?

If not, where would the electrophile prefer to attack on toluene?

Looking at related answers, it seems like hyperconjugation leads to delocalisation of electrons over the ring, like in resonance. But hyperconjugation is the interaction between $\sigma$ and $π$ orbitals, how does it lead to delocalisation *over the ring*? I cannot understand it in terms of the molecular orbital theory.

Lastly, would the electrophile prefer to attack at Ortho position due to greater $+I$ effect and (if possible) hyperconjugation effect? Please correct me if I'm missing something.

Comment: Related: [Inductive vs hyperconjuative effects in electrophilic aromatic substitution](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/81430/4945)

Answer (score 0):

sorry that was my mistake. the correct mechanism is this
[image]